# installation of cryptography fails in pip install `unicode` error

Tags: python, linux, installation, pip

I am trying to install `cryptography` and its fail with `unicode` error.

```
[root@localhost root]$ pip install "cryptography>=0.2.1"
Downloading/unpacking cryptography>=0.2.1
  Downloading cryptography-0.5.4.tar.gz (320kB): 320kB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/build/cryptography/setup.py) egg_info for package cryptography
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'libffi' found
    c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
    In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:43:
    c/malloc_closure.h:33: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_closureâ
    c/malloc_closure.h: In function âmore_coreâ:
    c/malloc_closure.h:69: warning: division by zero
    c/malloc_closure.h:96: error: âunion mmaped_blockâ has no member named ânextâ
    c/malloc_closure.h: At top level:
    c/malloc_closure.h:105: error: expected â)â before â*â token
    c/malloc_closure.h:113: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c:209: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_cifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_deallocâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: for each function it appears in.)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: expected expression before â)â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1524: warning: implicit declaration of function âcffi_closure_freeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_traverseâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: expected expression before â)â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_clearâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: expected expression before â)â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowning_reprâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1676: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:1676: error: expected expression before â)â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2222: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âffi_abiâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdata_callâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2356: error: âffi_abiâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2356: error: expected â;â before âfabiâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2398: error: âfabiâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2402: error: too many arguments to function âfb_prepare_cifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2407: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_sizeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2417: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2447: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2452: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_callâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:2452: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_new_primitive_typeâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3356: error: âffi_typeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3356: error: âffitypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3377: error: âffi_type_sint8â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3378: error: âffi_type_sint16â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3379: error: âffi_type_sint32â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3380: error: âffi_type_sint64â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3386: error: âffi_type_floatâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3388: error: âffi_type_doubleâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3390: error: âffi_type_longdoubleâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3396: error: âffi_type_uint8â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3397: error: âffi_type_uint16â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3398: error: âffi_type_uint32â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3399: error: âffi_type_uint64â undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3953: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_typeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:3972: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_buildâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: âffi_typeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: expected expression before â)â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4104: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4107: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4107: warning: implicit declaration of function âfb_fill_typeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4115: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4118: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4119: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4129: error: âatypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4142: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4143: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4146: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4153: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_sizeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_build_nameâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4175: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4184: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4186: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_prepare_ctypeâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4227: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4237: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4257: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âffi_abiâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_prepare_cifâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_prep_cifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âfabiâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âFFI_OKâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_new_function_typeâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4302: error: âFFI_DEFAULT_ABIâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4340: error: too many arguments to function âfb_prepare_cifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4348: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4358: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âconvert_from_object_fficallbackâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4382: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4454: error: expected â)â before â*â token
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_callbackâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4525: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4525: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4546: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4564: warning: implicit declaration of function âcffi_closure_allocâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4581: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_prep_closureâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4581: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4582: error: âinvoke_callbackâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c:4582: error: âFFI_OKâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âinit_cffi_backendâ:
    c/_cffi_backend.c:5511: error: âFFI_DEFAULT_ABIâ undeclared (first use in this function)
    compiling '_configtest.c':
    __thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 17, in <module>
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 174, in <module>
        "test": PyTest,
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup
        _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 262, in __init__
        self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 287, in fetch_build_eggs
        replace_conflicting=True,
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 886, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg
        return cmd.easy_install(req)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install
        return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item
        dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs
        return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install
        self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)
      File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1043, in run_setup
        raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

Package libffi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libffi.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'libffi' found

c/_cffi_backend.c:13:17: error: ffi.h: No such file or directory

In file included from c/_cffi_backend.c:43:

c/malloc_closure.h:33: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_closureâ

c/malloc_closure.h: In function âmore_coreâ:

c/malloc_closure.h:69: warning: division by zero

c/malloc_closure.h:96: error: âunion mmaped_blockâ has no member named ânextâ

c/malloc_closure.h: At top level:

c/malloc_closure.h:105: error: expected â)â before â*â token

c/malloc_closure.h:113: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token

c/_cffi_backend.c:209: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_cifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_deallocâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: for each function it appears in.)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1521: error: expected expression before â)â token

c/_cffi_backend.c:1524: warning: implicit declaration of function âcffi_closure_freeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_traverseâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1536: error: expected expression before â)â token

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowninggc_clearâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1552: error: expected expression before â)â token

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdataowning_reprâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:1676: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:1676: error: expected expression before â)â token

c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:

c/_cffi_backend.c:2222: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âffi_abiâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âcdata_callâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:2356: error: âffi_abiâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:2356: error: expected â;â before âfabiâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2398: error: âfabiâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:2402: error: too many arguments to function âfb_prepare_cifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2407: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_sizeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2417: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2447: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2452: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_callâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:2452: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_new_primitive_typeâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:3356: error: âffi_typeâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3356: error: âffitypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3377: error: âffi_type_sint8â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3378: error: âffi_type_sint16â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3379: error: âffi_type_sint32â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3380: error: âffi_type_sint64â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3386: error: âffi_type_floatâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3388: error: âffi_type_doubleâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3390: error: âffi_type_longdoubleâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3396: error: âffi_type_uint8â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3397: error: âffi_type_uint16â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3398: error: âffi_type_uint32â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:3399: error: âffi_type_uint64â undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:

c/_cffi_backend.c:3953: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before âffi_typeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:3972: error: expected â=â, â,â, â;â, âasmâ or â__attribute__â before â*â token

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_buildâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: âffi_typeâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4103: error: expected expression before â)â token

c/_cffi_backend.c:4104: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4107: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4107: warning: implicit declaration of function âfb_fill_typeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4115: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4118: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4119: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4129: error: âatypeâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4142: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4143: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4146: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_offset_argâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4153: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âexchange_sizeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_build_nameâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4175: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4184: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4186: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_prepare_ctypeâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4227: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4237: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âfctâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4257: error: expected declaration specifiers or â...â before âffi_abiâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âfb_prepare_cifâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_prep_cifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âfabiâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4284: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ârtypeâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named âatypesâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4285: error: âFFI_OKâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_new_function_typeâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4302: error: âFFI_DEFAULT_ABIâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4340: error: too many arguments to function âfb_prepare_cifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4348: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4358: error: âstruct funcbuilder_sâ has no member named ânargsâ

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âconvert_from_object_fficallbackâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4382: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c: At top level:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4454: error: expected â)â before â*â token

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âb_callbackâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:4525: error: âffi_closureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4525: error: âclosureâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4546: error: âffi_argâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4564: warning: implicit declaration of function âcffi_closure_allocâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4581: warning: implicit declaration of function âffi_prep_closureâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4581: error: âcif_description_tâ has no member named âcifâ

c/_cffi_backend.c:4582: error: âinvoke_callbackâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c:4582: error: âFFI_OKâ undeclared (first use in this function)

c/_cffi_backend.c: In function âinit_cffi_backendâ:

c/_cffi_backend.c:5511: error: âFFI_DEFAULT_ABIâ undeclared (first use in this function)

compiling '_configtest.c':

__thread int some_threadlocal_variable_42;

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/build/cryptography/setup.py", line 174, in <module>

    "test": PyTest,

  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 113, in setup

    _setup_distribution = dist = klass(attrs)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 262, in __init__

    self.fetch_build_eggs(attrs['setup_requires'])

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 287, in fetch_build_eggs

    replace_conflicting=True,

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve

    dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(req, ws, installer)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 874, in best_match

    return self.obtain(req, installer)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 886, in obtain

    return installer(requirement)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 338, in fetch_build_egg

    return cmd.easy_install(req)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 613, in easy_install

    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 643, in install_item

    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 833, in install_eggs

    return self.build_and_install(setup_script, setup_base)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1055, in build_and_install

    self.run_setup(setup_script, setup_base, args)

  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1043, in run_setup

    raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/build/cryptography
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 185, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/nileshkumar-govindbhai.patel/workspaces/gozer/horizon/.venv/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 161, in main
    text = '\n'.join(complete_log)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 75: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Its giving unicode error :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your actual problem is that you don't have [`libffi`](http://sourceware.org/libffi/) installed. You can see hundreds of messages about not being able to find `libffi` in the setup steps, and getting C compiler errors trying to include `ffi.h`, and so on. So, what you need to do is install it.

This is a C library, not a Python library. Your platform may have a package for it that you can install with `yum` or `apt` or `brew` or `port` or whatever; if not, you can download it and install it manually. (IIRC, you can just `./configure && make install`, but read the docs.) On some platforms, you may also need a `libffi-devel` or `libffi-dev` or `libffi-libs` or similar package.

Also, the fact that you don't have `libffi` also implies that you may not have the CPython development files (because on most platforms, they depend on `libffi`), which means you'll just run into another problem once you get past this one. These may be in a separate package from `python` named `python-devel` etc. (or maybe `python27-devel` or similar).

---

So, what's with the `UnicodeError` at the end? Well, you definitely do have something screwy with your setup. In all of your output, you get stuff like `âmore_coreâ`, apparently each `'` printing out as a `â`. That smells like Latin-1 vs. UTF-8 mojibake, but it's hard to be sure.

Anyway, at some point, Python is trying to generate some output (most likely either an exception message for the actual exception) that includes a `â` character (note that it's complaining about `0xe2`, and `'\xe2'.decode('latin-1')` is `u'â'`). But it's failed to detect your terminal, so it tries to encode the string to ASCII, and of course that fails, so it raises a `UnicodeError`, which hides the real error. (This is one of those things that was next to impossible to fix with the 2.x design without a ton of hackery, but which was fixed pretty early in the 3.x branch, and has been further improved since then. Unfortunately, you're still using 2.7, so that doesn't help you.)

Comment: I tried to install `libffi` and it says "Package libffi-3.0.5-3.2.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version"

Comment: @Lafada: OK, what about `libffi-devel`, or whatever your distro calls such packages, as I said in the very next paragraph? That's how you're going to get the `pkgconfig` record, the `.so` symlink, the header files, and all the other things you need to build anything that depends on `libffi`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` did it for me. Cheers abarnert

Comment: 'sudo yum install libffi-devel' did it for me on CentOS